# Full text search in loopback on User model via MondoDB connector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, search, loopbackjs

I want to search my User collection via full text search on both the firstName and lastName property.

I create my index like this:

```
     //connect to connector
    server.datasources.db.connector.connect(function (err, db) {

        //create index on firstName and lastName
        db.collection('User').createIndex(
            { firstName: "text", lastName: "text" },
            function (err) {
                if (!err) {

                    //run autoupdate on each model
                    Promise.each(server.models(), function (model) {
                        if (model.dataSource) {
                            var autoupdate = Promise.promisify(model.dataSource.autoupdate);
                            if (autoupdate) {
                                console.log("running autoupdate on model: " + model.modelName);
                                return autoupdate.call(model.dataSource, model.modelName);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
    });
```

But when i query the database for a search string i always get zero results via direct access:

```
var mongodb = models.User.getDataSource().connector.collection(models.User.modelName);

    mongodb.find({ $text: { $search: "Test" } },
        function (err, resp) {
            resp.toArray(function (err, docs) {
                //docs always empty
                cb(null, docs);
            });
        });
```

Or i get every entry when i use the Angular client like:

```
User.find({ where: { '$text': { search: "Test" } } }).$promise.then(function (resp) {
  console.log(resp)
});
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure the data is there? Like if you test w/ a vanilla Mongo client, do you get results?

Comment: If i remove { $text: { $search: "Test" } }, from my direct access query i get my expected 8 records including one which has lastName: "Tester" and should trigger the search. Additionally i can see my index when i log into my db via mongodb compass so this sould be fine as well

Comment: Hmm. But if you remove LoopBack from the picture and try in a simple JS file (run via Node of course), can you recreate the issue?

Comment: Tested it via the mongo shell and found one of the issues: For whatever reason i testet with a parial match, which is not supported. If i search for a full first or last name the results are fine with the direct query. what remains is the Angular query which still returns all entries. (I will edit my question)

Comment: I have few suggestions, why not extend the User model and work directly under customUser.js and have you added this option `allowExtendedOperators:true` (false by default) in your datasource.json under mongodb connector ? it allows you to use mongodb operators such as `$text` , `$search`